# Social media share preview link not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was trying to create a share preview link for whatsapp(fb, lkdin,..) and i have created a function that receives arguments and then `helmet` depending on the page where i am it would give to me the meta data updated.
Here is my function configuration:

```
    // React
    import React from 'react';
    import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

    // Helmet
    import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet';

    const HeaderMetaData = ({pageProps}) => {

        const title = pageProps.title ? pageProps.title : '';
        const description = pageProps.description ? pageProps.description : '';
        const image = require('../assets/images/image.png');
        
        return(
            <Helmet>
                <meta name="og:title" content={title} />
                <meta name="og:decription" content={description} />
                <meta name="og:image" content={image} />
            
            </Helmet>
        )
    }

    HeaderMetaData.propTypes = {
        title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        description: PropTypes.string.isRequired
    }

    export default HeaderMetaData;
```

And this function is called from another page and the following arguments are passed to it

```
<HeaderMetaData pageProps={course} />
```

Then in my `public/index.html`:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="./favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />

      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
      <meta property="title" content="page name" data-react-helmet="true" />
      <meta property="description" content="welcomeee" data-react-helmet="true" />
```

I feel that i missing something or maybe the metadata has to be the same like the `HeaderMetaData function`. When i check the metadata in console inspector it changes but it does not showing the preview link when i go to the page, the preview link works only with home, not where the function is called

Comment: Hello, As I was not aware of helmet library of react, I researched about it, I found this ( https://www.edwardbeazer.com/social-meta-tags/ ) blog which may be helpful for you. You code seems all good, but I guess you have to import helmet without curly bracket.

Comment: Hello, thanks for comment, i have read docs and saw a few vids and they use `{helmet}` for their examples as it shown here (https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet).

Comment: Can you please add the code of how and where you rendering headerMetadata component.

Comment: The function is called inside the return of a component.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, this is what I found:

> If the site is not static then you may expect this. As you are using
> client side routing (SPA) those kind of microdata tests require a
> proper server response... your server is probably responding as a 404
> for the path in question.

I guess that using a server to render the contents would help us to get around this issue.

For more information, read this thread: https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet/issues/624#issuecomment-765750657